# How to open wa.me link directly on Whastapp desktop application, rather than it redirecting to web (on PC)?

Tags: python-3.x, speech-recognition, whatsapp, pyttsx3

I am writing a Python script (3.10.2) which opens certain desktop applications via voice command using the ***pyttsx*3** and ***speech_recognition*** modules.

I thought of including *Whatsapp* into this script as well, and provided the **wa.me chat link** of one of my whatsapp contacts, which would open after a certain voice command is said.

However, the problem lies when it opens the link, instead of directly opening it on the Whatsapp desktop application (already downloaded from MSStore) it **redirects itself to the web** and then the prompt asks if to continue on web or to open the desktop application.

I want to make it, **directly opening the application**, rather than going through the **web prompts**. Is there a way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here. There are two ways one is this:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen("C:\\Windows\\System32\\whatsapp.exe")
```

Another is this:

```
import os
os.system("program_name")
```

Comment: thankyou for helping! Though I figured it out just a while after posting this. Went with the subprocess module way that you also mentioned with the help of cmd, it worked smoothly. Eg:- subprocess.Popen(["cmd", "/C", chatPath], shell=True) // chatPath = 'wa.me link'

Comment: oh yeah sure thing. This is my first time asking here, didnt realise that :p

Comment: It is fine welcome to Stack Overflow.